# Как удалить папку с содержимым? Например Download

Tags: android

Вот код на удаление файла или папки.
Код удаляет пустую папку, но удалять её с файлами не может!

```
String filePath = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath() + "/Download/ficha.phar";
  File file = new File(filePath);
  if (file.exists()) {
   file.delete();
  }
```

Данный код удаляет из памяти "телефона" в папке Download файл ficha

Кто-то может показать такой же код, но на удаление папки с тем что она содержит в себе!?

Answer (score 2):

Сначала удаляем все содержимое - затем саму папку. Для вложенных папок используем рекурсию:

```
public static boolean deleteDir(File dir) {
    if (dir.isDirectory()) {
        for (File child : dir.listFiles()) {
            boolean success = deleteDir(child);
            if (!success) {
                return false;
            }
        }
    }
    return dir.delete();
}
```

Использование:

```
if (deleteDir(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/Download")) {
    //удалено успешно
}
```

Бонус: можно еще использовать `FileUtils.deleteDirectory`

Comment: Файл еще может быть занят другим приложением. Проверка не должна быть на это? И это самый простой вариант, есть варианты и побыстрее, но больше и дольше писать надо.

Comment: @Александр Пузанов, я думаю если файл занят - он все равно удалится

Comment: Я всего лишь поднимаю вопрос надежности кода. Возможности проверить у меня нет.

Comment: Почему пишет ошибку в getExternalStorageDirectory?

Comment: я писал код без IDE. Это метод. Обновил ответ